# Implementing orphanRemoval in @OneToMany

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

So I'm trying to remove the the child in a onetomany relationship but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do. I was reading up how to do it online but many talked about entitymanager, cacasded, using queries etc. I'm unsure on which way to do it, usually I use crudrepository and simply do .save and .deleteById etc.

Here's what I have so far

```
@Entity
public class User

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Payment>payment = new ArrayList<Payment>();

getters/setters

@Service
public class UserService {


    public void addPayment(User user, Payment payment) {
        user.getPayment().add(payment);
        }
    
    public void removePayment(User user, Payment payment) {
        user.getPayment().remove(payment);
    }
```

Do I have to mess with the cascade type or entitymanager here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `user` method parameter is an managed Entity already associated with the session, then yes, that's the correct way to do it.

When the session gets flushed, Hibernate will delete the Payment instance which was removed from the users payments.

Comment: Is the @Entity auto-managed with the session? I extend my entity classes with crudrepositories

Comment: Assuming the `user` instance is loaded via findById() or something similiar from `CrudRepository`, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CascadeType.ALL. It work in my case.